# google custome search box result showing on same page or tab not on differrent page or tab

Tags: javascript, php

Here is link of site i am developing

http://ashteldemo.com/leonardpatel/

i have used google custom search box at top right of the page

when any one writes query and hit enter it should show result on different page or in different tab but it is showing result on the same page or same tab

here is code provided by google:

```
<script>
(function() {
var cx = '006011017794504203273:7s66ki24jds';
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

what can be solution to this ?, i want to show search result on different tab or

Answer (score 2):

You could try inserting the Google search form using HTML, and then setting the target on the submit button.

For example,

```
<form id="cse-search-box" action="http://google.com/cse">
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="YOUR SEARCH ENGINE ID goes here" />
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
<input type="submit" name="sa" target="_blank" value="Search" />
</form>
<img src="http://www.google.com/cse/images/google_custom_search_smwide.gif">
```

https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1351747?hl=en